# IBM Personality Insights Syntax Errors

Tags: python, syntax-error, ibm-watson, personality-insights

I'm trying to learn the basic of how the IBM Watson Personality Insights API works before it shuts down at the end of this year. I have a basic text file that I want analyzed, but I'm having trouble getting the code to run properly. [I have been trying to follow along on the official sits instructions](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/personality-insights?code=python#authentication), but I'm stuck. What am I doing wrong? (I have blotted out my key in the below code).

```
from ibm_watson import PersonalityInsightsV3
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('BlottedOutKey')
personality_insights = PersonalityInsightsV3(
    version='2017-10-13',
    authenticator=authenticator
)

personality_insights.set_service_url('https://api.us-west.personality-insights.watson.cloud.ibm.com')
with open(join(C:\Users\AWaywardShepherd\Documents\Data Science Projects\TwitterScraper-master\TwitterScraper-master\snscrape\python-wrapper\Folder\File.txt), './profile.json')) as profile_json:
    profile = personality_insights.profile(
        profile_json.read(),
        content_type='text/plain',
        consumption_preferences=True,
        raw_scores=True)
    .get_result()
print(json.dumps(profile, indent=2))
```

I keep getting the following nondescript syntax error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-1c7761f3f3ea>", line 11
    with open(join(C:\Users\AWaywardShepherd\Documents\Data Science Projects\TwitterScraper-master\TwitterScraper-master\snscrape\python-wrapper\Folder\File.txt), './profile.json')) as profile_json:
                    ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

There is so much wrong with that `open` line.

- join is expecting an itterable which it joins into a single string.
- In Python, strings become strings by enclosing them with quotes (paths are just strings !)
- You are only passing one value into join, which makes it redundant.
- The second parameter for open should be a mode, and not a file name.
- It looks like you are trying to append a directory with a file name, but for that to work the directory shouldn't end with a filename.
- The brackets don't match - You have 2 opening brackets and 3 closing brackets.

In Python you use `join` to join strings to gather. Normally this would be a path and a filename. Getting the path from the current working directory and joining it with a path.

```
import os

file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'profile.json')
```

In your code you are only passing in one string, so there is no need to use join.

Using `open` you pass in the filename and the mode. The mode would be something like `'r'` indicating read mode. So the code with the join becomes.

```
import os

with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'profile.json'), 'r') as profile_json:
```